# JFrame form border state not changing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

In Java, I have taken a `JFrame` with one `JButton` inside it,
when the frame starts, it starts normally with borders,

But my need is that when I click the button it turns into plain form
(means titleless/without borders) and again when I click my button it show with borders again (with title), but it does not work as simple I have written above.

I am using button `ActionListener` event and mentioned inside it the code is as follows:

```
if (frame.isUndecorated())
   frame.setUndecorated(true);
else
   frame.setUndecorated(false);
```

But my frame border state not changing but throwing too many exceptions.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: You can't change the border state of a frame which is already visible on the screen.  I think you'll need to create a new frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the border state of of a window that has already been made displayable (attached to a native peer)

Normally, I would suggest disposing of the old window and re-creating, but there's a little trick you can use...

Setting the `defaultCloseOperation` of the frame to `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` you can call `dispose` on the frame and it will release all it's native resources, allowing to change the border state and re-display it, for example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JButton btn = new JButton("Change");
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.windowForComponent((JButton)e.getSource());
                        frame.dispose();
                        if (frame.isUndecorated()) {
                            frame.setUndecorated(false);
                        } else {
                            frame.setUndecorated(true);
                        }
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    }

                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(btn);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yep, freaked me out too, I was all prepared to remove the content pane and add it to another frame...

Comment: thanks, really i got, what i were missing, thanks again for throwing angel light on me, ..... :D